# ¿Si añado un archivo al gitignore tras varios commits, este se oculta en los anteriores?

Tags: git, github

Para empezar, recientemente aprendí a usar git y github, por lo que soy bastante nuevo en esto y lo estoy utilizando para el programa de un estacionamiento en el que estoy trabajando. Ahora, el problema es que me han dicho que debo hacer el repositorio público y que por tanto, debo ocultar el archivo de configuración para el programa con el gitignore, pero ya he realizado varios commits hasta el momento y recién voy a utilizar el gitignore, ahora mi duda es, ¿si lo añado ahora, el archivo también se ocultara para commits anteriores? Aunque esto es una opción, preferentemente optaría por lo siguiente: ¿puedo cambiar el contenido del archivo de configuración, que es un json por cierto, solo dejando las claves y vaciando los valores de estas desde el primer commit? Pido disculpas por lo enredado que suena y por mi poca experiencia pero espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No. Todo lo que esta comiteado, no se va a ocultar ahora. Para lo que queres hacer, tenes que mirar aca: https://docs.github.com/es/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, las revisiones que ya hiciste así van a quedar y agregar un `.gitignore` no va a modificarlas de forma retroactiva (por cuestiones de seguridad, entre otras). Lo que puedes hacer es *reescribir la historia* del proyecto para que el `.gitignore` entre desde la primera revisión y evitas agregar el archivo de configuración. Si tu proyecto es sencillo, con una rama recta, puedes hacer esto, asumiendo que la rama principal se llama `main` (guarda una copia del archivo de configuración fuera del repositorio, porque lo podrías destruir en el proceso si el archivo ha sido modificado varias veces en la historia del proyecto):

```
git rebase --root -i
```

Te va a salir la lista de revisiones, desde la mas antigua (la primera) a la mas nueva (la última). La acción de cada revision es `pick`. Vas a cambiar la acción de la primera revisión por `edit` (o `e`). Guardas y sales del editor. El rebase va a arrancar y se va a detener luego de aplicar la primera revisión.

En este punto es donde te gustaría *eliminar* el archivo de configuración y pedirle a git que lo ignore de ahora en adelante, cierto?

```
git checkout main -- .gitignore # trae el archivo .gitignore de la rama main
```

Si el archivo no existe en la rama `main`, entonces crea un archivo `.gitignore` con la ruta al archivo de configuración y entonces haces

```
git add .gitignore
```

Ahora pídele a git que saque (borrer) el archivo de configuración:

```
git rm --cached el-archivo-de-configuracion # borralo del index, pero déjalo en mi árbol de trabajo
```

En este punto, podemos *enmendar* la primera revisión que ya no tendrá el archivo de configuración y que lo va a ignorar de ahora en adelante.

```
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

En este punto tienes una nueva primera revisión que ya no tiene el archivo de configuración y que ignora el archivo de configuración. Como lo podemos verificar?

```
git status --ignored
```

Debería mostrar que el archivo de configuración está siendo ignorado.

A continuación solo hay que correr

```
git rebase --continue
```

Con esto el resto de la historia del proyecto debería montarse sobre la nueva revisión. El único problema que podrías tener al hacer esto es que te salgan conflictos *precisamente* sobre el archivo de configuración (si en la rama original modificabas el archivo y guardabas una nueva revisión). En ese caso se produciría un `conflicto de árbol` (en una rama el archivo no existe, en la otra fue modificado). Lo que haces es decirle a git que no le pare al archivo cada vez que se detenga:

```
git rm --cached el-archivo-de-configuracion
git rebase --continue
```

Y así hasta que corra completo sin detenerse por conflictos. En ese punto tienes una rama que va a ignorar el archivo de configuración y que ya no tiene el archivo de configuración en su historia. Si la rama la quieres subir a un remoto donde ya hay revisiones de las viejas, al hacer el push haces `git push --force` **y** no vayas a hacer pull o merge contra una rama de las viejas porque la c%g%s.

Probablemente haya otros detalles que trabajar en el proceso pero eso es lo importante.

Comment: ¿Y en caso de que tenga una rama hay que hacer pasos adicionales o no es posible arreglarlo? Por cierto, muchas gracias por la respuesta. :)

Comment: @fcocaceresc lee los enlaces que te pase.. la forma de decir gracias aqui es puntuando las respuestas, y aceptandolas en caso de que funcionen y hayan solucionado tu problema

Comment: que quieres decir con que tienes una rama? Justamente la receta es para una rama.

Comment: En todo caso, si quieres hacer una reescritura de un proyecto complejo, deberías mirar https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo